# Long and inconsistent updates times of content in content by search web part

Tags: 2013, search, crawling, content-search-web-part, content-source

We run SharePoint Server 2013 for our company intranet portal. On this portal we have a news functionality, based on the standard blog site template, and we show the latest blog posts via a Content by Search web part on the intranet homepage.

This web part is configured to show, amongst other things, the comments and Likes of a post. This works: the data shows up correctly in the content by search web part.

However, the problem is that there frequently (but not always) is a long delay between the publishing of the post/like/comment and the moment at which these updates are reflected in the content by search web part on the homepage. It is very inconsistent: sometimes it takes 3 minutes, other times it takes 6 hours before a post or comments/like show up (sometimes the post shows up, but the comments/likes counters are not yet updated correctly).

Question is: why? Is this a content source crawl setting (search service) in central admin or is it something else? (All content sources are set to "incremental crawl"). Is it considered Local SharePoint content (the blog posts) or People/OneDrive content (comments/likes?) What could it be? Your help would be very appreciated.

**Additional details:**

Display name: Aantal leuk – Internal name: LikesCount – Mapped managed property: none

Display name: Aantal commentaren – Internal name: NumComments  - mapped to managed property: RefinableInt02

Answer (score 2):

To improve your application (to reduce the time difference between new item added/changes and that to reflect on your content Search webpart) , you can try below things:

1. Create a separate content source for your application site collection.(This is to reduce the crawl duration)
2. Configure continuous crawl for that content source.The default interval of continuous crawl is 15 minutes and the lowest you can set is 1 minute.

You can run below powershell command and reduce the crawl interval:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$ssa.SetProperty("ContinuousCrawlInterval",n)
```

Now back to your initial question of the why it takes sometimes 3 minutes and sometimes long hours: this is because incremental crawl might be already started when your new item was added(3 mins scenario) and the other times the items are added during the break between consecutive incremental crawl.